# Generate random String in Java without using random class or method directly for string

Tags: java

I am trying to write down the code to generate the random string of 5 characters from a predefined string.

My goal is to create a String array of length 5, and store all 5 random strings in this array.

So, far I have written below code:

```
public static String generateRandomString(int stringlength, String fullstring){
        //Generating random number which will use to pick character from provider string at index[i]
        int i =((int)(Math.random()*100));

        //Created a character array to store the characters picked up from provided String
        char [] randomString = new char[5];

        //Checking the condition if generated random number is greater than or equals to string length to avoid OutOfBoundException
        if (i>=stringlength){
            generateRandomString(stringlength, fullstring);
        }
        //Else Fetching the character from provided string and storing it into Char[]
        else
        {

                randomString [0] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
                randomString [1] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
                randomString [2] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
                randomString [3] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
                randomString [4] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
        }
        //Converting Char[] to String.
        String returnString = new String(randomString);

        //Returning String
        return returnString;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //String Array to Store Random Strings
        String [] array = new String[5];

        //Provided String
        String fullstring = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int stringlength = fullstring.length();

        //Loop to store random strings into all indexes of String[]
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){

        array[j]=generateRandomString(stringlength, fullstring);
        }

        //Printing Final String[]
        for(String var:array){
            System.out.println(var);
        }

    }
```

**But I am facing two issues:**

1. I want my random string to not contain only single character, my current code is picking only one character for all 5 places. Because it is taking one value (i). I want to change my value of (i) to again any random value after every character stored for one index at char[].

**e.g.**

I am getting "aaaaa" for one random string but I want like "auzje"

2. When I am printing the Final String[], sometimes I am getting NULL string in my output.

**e.g.** 
"     "

"aaaaa"

"     "

"ggggg"

"iiiii"

**What I am finally looking for is:**

"ajsuh"

"ldugj"

"odueb"

"mcnde"

"yahnf"

Please suggest.

Many Thanks.

Comment: `randomString [0] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
                randomString [1] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
                randomString [2] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
                randomString [3] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
                randomString [4] = (fullstring.charAt(i));` is your culprit. Try debugging why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change

```
if (i>=stringlength){
    generateRandomString(stringlength, fullstring);
} else { // this is where you're saving all similar characters to the array
    randomString [0] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
    randomString [1] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
    randomString [2] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
    randomString [3] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
    randomString [4] = (fullstring.charAt(i));
}
```

to

```
randomString [0] = (fullstring.charAt((int)(Math.random()*100) % stringlength));
randomString [1] = (fullstring.charAt((int)(Math.random()*100) % stringlength));
randomString [2] = (fullstring.charAt((int)(Math.random()*100) % stringlength));
randomString [3] = (fullstring.charAt((int)(Math.random()*100) % stringlength));
randomString [4] = (fullstring.charAt((int)(Math.random()*100) % stringlength));
```

Though the code can further be cleaned and abstracted but shall assign random characters from your `fullstring` to `char[]`'s different indexes.

Comment: It perfectly works for me.. but I am still not getting what I was missing, sorry for asking but I am new in Java. Can you please some more light on the mistake in mycode which I have wrote. Thanks.

Comment: As mentioned in your code block's comment. You were using same constant value of `i` for storing the character in different indexes of `randomString[]` hence the duplicity of the same character 5 times.

Comment: Yes, but why it was giving NULL string at the time of printing the Array (Issue 2 from my query)?

Comment: @Shan Does it print `"null"` or `""` empty string in few cases?

Comment: Sorry, it was empty string with some spaces, and also sometimes it was printing only empty strings.

Comment: Sir, have you looked at my issue 2, though it is not occurring after applying your code. But it will be very useful for me to get the answer so I will take care of it from the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a new character for each output symbol. Assuming you are using Java 8+, you can generate a `Stream` of random characters from your input `fullstring` - limit it to `stringlength` and then collect to a `String`; like,

```
public static String generateRandomString(int stringlength, String fullstring) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> Character.toString(fullstring.charAt( //
            (int) (Math.random() * fullstring.length())))) //
            .limit(stringlength).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Then, when invoking it, again generate random five character `String`(s) and limit it to the desired five `String`(s) and finally collect it. Using an array is perhaps a little clunky, but can be achieved like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fullstring = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String[] r = Stream.generate(() -> generateRandomString(5, fullstring)) //
            .limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[5]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple but a bit memory hungry way to do so is by defining an array of the acceptable characters and picking a index by using the Random class or Math.random()

Example:

```
String randomString(int length, char[] chars)
{
      char[] result = new char[length];
      Random rand = new Random();
      for(int x = 0; x < length; x++)
          result [x] = chars [Math.abs(rand.nextInt())%chars.length];
       return new String(result);
}
```